# Error:'Int64Index' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so my code looks like this:

```
for x in df.index():
df.index[x] = pd.to_datetime(index[x],unit='ms')
x=x+1
```

the index in this dataframe is a bunch of unix timestamp that I wanted to convert to readable format. Example below:

```
                         a                b                          c
1367280000000         135.3         1501657493.0                 0.0
1367366400000         117.0         1298951550.0                 0.0
1367452800000        103.43         1148667722.0                 0.0
```

this is the typeError I got:

```
for x in df.index():
TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `index` attribute and `to_datetime()` method:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index,unit='ms')
```